# Sencha build failed when running command sencha build app native

Tags: sencha-cmd

getting this error

```
[ERR] Total time: 2 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
build-impl.xml:381: The following error occur
red while executing this line:
impl.xml:372: com.sencha.exceptions.BasicException: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Hi, you need to post more information. Version of Touch/ExtJS, Cmd version, Cordova/PhoneGap and also steps which you did so far to get to this error.

Comment: Enviornment:
java 1.7
Ruby 1.9
senhca cmd 5.1.2.52
cordova 6.1.0
phonegap 6.0.3
senhca sdk 2.4.1 on already created sencha project i have to build apk for that i did firstly senhca phonegap init and then senhca app build native